# Selenium WebDriver- How to specify Firefox binary location (c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Can someone advise me on how to set the path for the firefox exe file in Selenium using C#?
This is what I thought would help but there is no ctor taking in just the FirefoxBinary:

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary("~/lib/mozilla firefox/firefox.exe");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary); //not a valid constructor
```

Comment: `public FirefoxDriver(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile);`
Click F12 on `FirefoxDriver` and you can go into the class.

Comment: What do I set in the Firefox profile?

Comment: `FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();` Or set null

Answer (score 2):

try following code

```
//give exe path here
 var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService("~/lib/mozilla firefox/firefox.exe");
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

if any issue the let me know.